# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0, json.loads

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm a little bit new coding. I have an API that works perfectly sending the request from browser but when I try to run it with python requests it returns `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

This is a part of my API:

```
post_data = json.loads(request.body.getvalue().decode('utf-8'))
run = postdata['run']
response = postdata['response']
```

and my requests with python is:

```
payload = {"run":1, "response" : "https://sampleserver"}
headers = {"content-type" : "application/json"}
r = requests.post("http://myserver", data = payload, headers = headers)
```

I think that maybe the problem is in the `post_data`

Comment: How are the two code snippets connected? You use `requests.post()` in the second. What is `request.body` in the first?

Comment: the request.body is defined in the run and response and I set this values in postman. The second is another python script. @quamrana

Comment: I still don't get why you included the second snippet. The error occurs in the first. What has the second to do with that?

Comment: `post_data = r.json()`

Comment: error means that you didn't get JSON data. You should first display what you get in `r.text` (or `request.body.getvalue()`) to see you didn't get some HTML with explanation.

Comment: if you want to send values as JSON then you should use `post(...,  json=payload)` instead of `data=payload` (which send it as `form` data). And when you use `json=...` then you don't have to add header `"application/json"` because it will add it automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't show link to API documentation but I assume that you have to send data as `JSON` so you have to use `json=payload` instead of `data=payload`

And when you use `json=` then you don't have to add header `"application/json"` because it will add it automatically.

```
payload = {
    "run": 1, 
    "response" : "https://sampleserver",
}

r = requests.post("http://myserver", json=payload)
```

`data=` sends it as `form` data like `run=1&response=http://myserver`

---

**BTW:**

Next time when you get `JSONDecodeError:` then first check what you get `request.body` before you try to convert it to from `JSON` because error means that data is not correct `JSON` - and you should see data to see if you get `JSON` data, `form` data (`run=1&response=..`) or some `HTML` with warning or explanation.

Comment: I'm getting the same error, and I don't know where in my code it comes from, in the debug page it points to `body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
    data = json.loads(body_unicode) `

Comment: @DerekPK first check what you have in `print( body_unicode )` because error means you don't get `JSON` data. Maybe you get some HTML with warning or some explanation. And better create question on new page to show FULL error code and URL which makes this problem.

Comment: I found the problem, I had an `DecimalField` instead of an `IntegerField`, but I wanted to use `DecimalField`, without getting the error, how can I do that?

Comment: @furas I can't make more Questions, because my old questions didn't get any good rating.

Comment: Solved: I used float and it solved the problem.